# Does "ta'anas besulim" (claims of virginity) exist nowadays?

Tags: ketubah, maseches-kesubos

The first few *perakim* of Maseches Kesuvos deal extensively with *ta'anas besulim* (claims of virginity).

As this doesn't require the Beis Hamikdash to be around, and-- since it's a monetary matter-- can be brought to a Beis Din of 3:

- Is this still applicable nowadays? If so, are there places/ communities in the world where it is enforced? (ie America, Israel etc)
- Why/ why not?

Sources welcome please- thanks!

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.68.1

Comment: Mainly not, because nowadays, erusin & nisuin are done very close to another.

Comment: The issue is addressed [here](http://www.kiryatmoshe.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8/436-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A1%D7%97#_Toc526286299) tl;dr there are several reasons for doubt, in addition to Rafael's correct observation (which reduces the scope of the question to when the bride was single). Therefore we do not judge such cases.

Comment: FYI, practically, many if not most Haredi Yeshivisher guys have problems performing during the first night. Usually, it takes weeks and sometimes months until they learn the drill. So this Taanah is hardly applicable.

Comment: I think you should add @Dr.Shmuel's link to Sho"a and say that Hamechaber clearly ruled that there is! So your question would be if it continues today or was somehow abandoned (as Josh mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

See Gemara Ketubbot 10a. There two types of Taanat betulim. Firstly Taanat Damim, he claims that there was no blood, secondly Taanat "opened door". The first is valid for a little girl and for an adult (> 12) woman. The second is valid only for a girl little than 12½. There are families of ill girls who have not noticeable bleeding, and therefore there is no Taanat Damim. For Taanat opened door, the man cannot argue it if he's not accustomed with sexual relationships. There is no suspicion of lie because he would not lose the wedding expanse, but doubt about his insight. All this rules are listed in SA EH 68.

Consequences of Taanat betulim nowadays that Nisuin are immediately after Kiddushin is monetary only, not to make her pesula because of adultery.

If he wanted a betula Davka, his Taanat Damim isn't sufficient to claim that ketbba needs to be resdtitued because her claim is not nothing. She could argue that she was betula after an Oath.

The monetary challenge regards the 100--200, not the supplement.

There  are two differences between nowadays an Gemara times. Today bride is adult, and there is no safek adultery between Kiddushin and nisuyin.

I'd seen multiple articles and as I assumed there is still Taanat betulim today.

[1](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-13/)

[2](http://www.kiryatmoshe.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8/436-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A1%D7%97)